# How to create an array of list of class objects in C#

Tags: c#

My C# class is as follows

```
public class SeatPlans
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string seat_id { get; set; }
    public string seat_no { get; set; }
    public int layout_id { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a list of class object as follows

```
List<SeatPlans> allUser = new List<SeatPlans>();
```

but what I need is an array of lists so that I can access the data of several objects like `allUser[0]`, `allUser[1]`, `allUser[2]`

My controller code is as follows

```
public JsonResult getdata(int seat_plane_id)
{
    int lid = seat_plane_id;
    layoutsController L = new layoutsController();
    JsonResult result = L.getlayouts(lid);

    List<layouts> L1 = (List<layouts>)result.Data;
    List<List<SeatPlans>> allUser = new List<List<SeatPlans>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < L1.Count; i++)
    {
        String lid1 = L1[i].ticket_no_start;
        lid = Int32.Parse(lid1);
        allUser[i] = db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList();
    }

    var v = new { allUser = allUser[0], allUser1 = allUser[1] };

    return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'm getting

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException exception

at

```
allUser[i] = db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList();
```

Comment: You can still access the list item by index using `allUser[0]`. So getting the Id would be `allUser[0].Id`

Comment: allUser[0] contain the value of Id right?,but actualy i nee a separate list of classes in allUser[0],allUser[1],allUser[2]

Comment: Yes, you can access all the public properties this way.

Comment: i need something like this   ---                                                      allUser[0] = db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList();                         allUser[1] = db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList();

Comment: ToList() returns a list.  Trying to set to allUser[0] doesn't make sense unless you really want List<List<SeatPlans>>.  You may need to use a GroupBy to take the List<SeatPlans> and break into groups so you would have a List<List<SeatPlans>>

Comment: Rename the class to SeatPlan. That might make the code more readable. (I even doubt the name SeatPlan)

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd you're right. the plural name is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an array of lists you can simply declare it:

```
List<SeatPlans>[] allUsers = new List<SetPlans>[size];
```

then you can get specific list by index:

```
allUsers[1] = new List<SetPlans>();
```

to get specific element of specific list:

```
SeatPlans specificSeatPlans = allUsers[1][2];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use allUser[0],allUser[1],allUser[2] with List as well. allUser[0] gets the first SeatPlan object then you can access public members from that.

```
SeatPlan sp = allUser[0];
Console.Writeline(sp.Id);
```

will print out the first SeatPlan object's Id.

Comment: if i use the allUser[0] instead allUser it shows error(red marks)

Comment: @rakshi can you post your code where you are trying to use it.

Comment: sir i have posted my controller

Answer (score 1):

If you need an 2d array of objects you can create it like this:

```
List<List<SeatPlan>> allUser = new List<List<SeatPlan>>();

allUser.Add(db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList());
```

note, you need to use the `Add` method to push a new object onto the list.

Accessing the individual objects can then be done via `allUser[0][0]`, getting the Id for example would be `allUser[0][0].Id`

Comment: i am getting System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException from the point---              allUser[0] = db.SEATPLAN.Where(d => d.layout_id == lid).ToList();

Comment: You can't initialize a list that way. The constructor creates a 0 size List so allUser[0] doesn't exist yet. You have you use the `Add` method like in my answer.